# PHP IF Statement within HTML FORM

Tags: php, html, if-statement

Can you put a PHP IF() statement within an HTML form?

I am looking to make an adaptive form depending on the previous selected options.

Snippet:

```
<label for="#">Pick a #:</label><br/>
<select id="#" name="#" form="#" value="<?php echo $#;?>" required>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select><br/>
        <br/>
 <label for="Reason">Reason:</label><br/>
 <select id="Reason" name="Reason" form="Reason" value="<?php echo $Reason;?>" required>
        <?php

        if ($# === "1"){
        ?>
            <option value="R1">Unique</option>
            <option value="R2">Lonely</option>
            <option value="R3">Supreme Leader</option>
            <option value="R4">Excess Space</option>
        <?php
        }
```

The selection box does appear, but with no drop-downs, regardless what is selected in the "#" section.

Not opposed to using Javascript, just wondering if this is possible.

Comment: No. This isn't possible as you describe. As you may be expecting, this has to be done with JS.

Comment: That's not how PHP works, the page needs to be submitted first.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what it is that you're trying to do

Comment: `$#` is not even a valid variable name

Comment: Technically you could have php return the next set of options, but it would need to be done via an ajax call which would still involve javascript, so you'd be as well just doing the whole thing with javascript unless you have specific reasons for contacting the server between each question

Comment: @u_mulder I suspect the OP just used `#` as representative of a name to avoid using the real ID, he could equally have used `my_var`, notice how the `#` is used in many places wherever a name or ID should be

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and comments. Off to Javascript I go.

Answer (score 3):

This interaction, as you've mentioned, has to be dealt with in the client side and (probably) with JavaScript.
PHP only processes the page on the server side once and then the page is submitted to the client. Once it's there, PHP is long gone and has no effect on the page.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and comments. Off to Javascript I go.